# Is there a way to fill out an Excel workbook without involving Excel itself? Or can I force Excel to quit?

Tags: c#, excel

I am creating a web page to select data to download an Excel workbook (complete with macros), with that data filled in to the appropriate cells.

I was given a .vbs as a starting point for filling out an Excel workbook.

In the .vbs, the original programmer calls

```
Set objExcel =  CreateObject("Excel.Application")
set ObjWorkbook =objExcel.Workbooks.Open(blankFile)
`...
objWorkbook.Saveas(outputFile)
objExcel.Quit
```

I'm trying to make a web page using C# and MVC, so I looked into `Excel.Application` and found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.application.aspx) and [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/302084/how-to-automate-microsoft-excel-from-microsoft-visual-c--net). I developed an action, just to test things out:

```
public FileResult filledOutWorkbook()
{
    Excel.Application oXL;
    Excel._Workbook oWB;
    Excel._Worksheet oSheet;
    Excel.Range oRng;

    oXL = new Excel.Application();
    oXL.Visible = false;

    oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Worksheet2.xlsm"));
    oSheet = oWB.Sheets["Information Sheet"];

    oSheet.Range["V2"].Value2 = "customer test lol";

    if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/temp")))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/temp"));
    }
    var filename = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/temp/") + DateTime.Now.ToString("o").Replace(":", "") + ".xlsm";
    oWB.SaveCopyAs(filename);

    oXL.Visible = false;
    oXL.Quit();

    return File(filename, "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12", "Worksheet.xlsm");
}
```

(I'm going to do a scheduled task or something to clear these out because I'm pretty sure I can't just get a byte stream of the file.)

The problem is, this doesn't close Excel. Apparently C# is not interacting with a library that understands Excel workbooks' formatting, you're automating Excel. I would install Excel on the production server, but when I tell it to quit Excel it doesn't quit. It asks the user if they want to save changes to the template document. I don't know how many times this page is going to get used but I think it's bad practice to have to click "no" however many times on the server to free up memory.

Can I circumvent this? Is there a better library than the COM object Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel? Can I force Excel to close or is my best bet to write all the Excel interaction in VB and call that from the controller action?

Comment: Have you tried forcing it to close without saving? Try `WB.Close(false);` before your `oXL.Quit();`

Comment: you never freed COM objects you obtained. excel will never fully quit until you do so

Comment: @Steve Setting reference to `null`, using `GC.Collect`, and calling `Quit` will be enough to clean up Excel.

Comment: @DaveCousineau not always. you could run into memory corruption that way. had experienced that in the past

Comment: @Steve "memory corruption"? I have dozens of applications that do this without issue.

Comment: @DaveCousineau I do have a reproducible example in my previous work place but not anymore. basically if you have too many COM objects and you completely rely on GC then it might happen

Comment: @Steve I suspect it may be something else. For example, one thing never to do is expose interop types on the public interface. All interop types should be wrapped and hidden in your own public classes. I would be interested to see an example.

Comment: @DaveCousineau the sample application does not expose any api or allow any external calls. So the only possibility to mess up memory is due to COM (native resource) objects. The exception is either AccessViolation or .NET heap corruption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone who has used and suffered with the Microsoft Excel Interoperability Library, I'm glad you are looking for an alternative.

Don't get me wrong. The interoperability library is extremely useful if you're trying to automate some simple task with small amounts of data. But it's ridiculously slow when it involves large amounts of data. And if you want this on a web server, you need to have Excel Installed on the server as well.

I suggest you use ClosedXML. It's open source and MIT licensed. It's basically a wrapper around OpenXML. It's also very easy to use, much faster and doesn't need Excel installed on the server

https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML

Comment: I have used ClosedXML a little bit, and it's quite nice.  I'm more familiar with EPPLus, which is nails.  If you haven't tried it out, do so.  Just as you said with ClosedXML, it really takes away much of the agony of using interop.  One of the true pains of interops is the muted ability to use Intellisense.

Comment: Agree with avoiding having to install Excel on your server if at all possible, it greatly complicates licensing as well and is strongly recommended against by MS:
https://serverfault.com/a/375417
`Current licensing guidelines prevent Office applications from being used on a server to service client requests, unless those clients themselves have licensed copies of Office.`

Comment: _One of the true pains of interops is the muted ability to use Intellisense._ How can I forget that? The amount of time I spent looking at possible methods and properties rather than actually working while using the Interop library was obscenely high

Answer (score 2):

If it asks you to save, then it means it thinks the workbook has unsaved changes. Just close the workbook and don't save changes before quitting:

```
oWB.Close(false);
```

You might also need to close the first default workbook, in fact that might actually be the one that's causing the save message. Look for another workbook and close it without saving. Something like:

```
oXL.Workbooks[0].Close(false);
```

Or just enumerate the collection and close all of them.

It will depend on the actual state that Excel is in. If you're unsure of what to do, show Excel instead of closing it, and try to see what it is that it thinks is unsaved and decide if you want to save it or discard it.

Answer (score 2):

You have two good answers here, but as an alternative, you could also tell Excel to suspend warnings.  This is helpful any time you do something that would normally prompt a dialog, such as "Save As" on a file that already exists.

The `DisplayAlerts` property on the Excel object controls this and is true by default.  Changing it to false will suspend alerts, so this should also work:

```
application.DisplayAlerts = false;
application.Quit();
application.DisplayAlerts = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you take a different approach here.  I would create a tab in the excel workbook where the user enters their choices that drive the data selection.  Then write some script to use those settings to pull the data from a web service.  See this article as an example: https://atinkerersnotebook.com/2012/12/28/creating-consuming-web-services-with-excel/

Now all you have to do is write the web service to return the requested data.

Answer (score 0):

I want to suggest a bit of a different way to generate an excel file. For medium complexity worksheets it's much easier to use Report Designer to design the report, and then export it to an excel file. It can be generated to a stream, you don't even have to generate a file.