# Excel does not Quit C#

Tags: c#, excel, c#-4.0, vba

I am writing this particular code in C# to write to an excel file.

```
public partial class WriteExcelForm : Form
{
    public WriteExcelForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void writeExcelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        if (xlApp == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Excel is not installed!!!");
            return;
        }

        Excel.Workbooks xlWorkBooks = xlApp.Workbooks;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlWorkBooks.Add(Type.Missing);
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet;
        xlWorkSheet.Name = "sample";

        Excel.Range range1 = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
        range1.Value = "dhiraj";

        Excel.Range range2 = xlWorkSheet.Range["A2"];
        range2.Value = "dhiraj";

        xlWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\\output.xlsx");

        //Properly closing the excel app
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        xlWorkBook.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        xlApp.Quit();

        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(range1);
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(range2);
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorkBooks);
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlApp);
    }
}
```

If I run this code, the excel.exe does not quit, but keeps on hanging around in the background.

However, if I comment out this particular line

```
        Excel.Range range1 = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
        range1.Value = "dhiraj";
```

the excel.exe quits elegantly.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT:**
I have solved my issue. Posting my findings as answer.

P.S: Do not know why I was down voted, I did research a lot before posting this question.

Comment: @YowE3K: You mean without the explicit Type Casting? I did tried that, but i end up with the same result.

Comment: Check this link: http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/08/06/vb-net-two-dot-rule-when-working-with-office-applications-2/ - and eliminate the double dots. Also suggest you avoid using the brackets notation to do type conversion.

Comment: And see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29067714/vsto-manipulating-com-objects-one-dot-good-two-dots-bad - for a counter point.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie: I have gone through those links, I hope you don't see any "double dots" in the code that I have shared here.

Comment: Maybe it's the cast using brackets?

Comment: Every `[]` is a hidden period. https://ausdotnet.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/com-interop-principle-3-fear-the-hidden-period/

Comment: Are you sure that **all** workbooks have been closed (including workbooks that have been opened from outside your code)? (You can enforce that by looping through the workbooks object)

Some of your variables (for instance **range1**) are still pointing to the closed workbook. It might help if you clear them before trying to quit the excel application.

Comment: Not sure if this will help or not, but check this out:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47418452/is-there-a-way-to-fill-out-an-excel-workbook-without-involving-excel-itself-or.  I think the reason it works when you omit that line of code is because you haven't altered the workbook, which prevents the "Save document?" dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I continued my research after asking the question, and I found this particular link 
[How do I properly clean up Excel interop objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-do-i-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects)

Now in this particular link, three answers which when put together helped me out.

First answer is this particular one https://stackoverflow.com/a/158752/2241802 
It says to avoid using "Never use two dots with COM objects".

Second answer is this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/159419/2241802 
This answer refers to how to use excel object practically and it is very important to follow this, since I will not be the only developer working on my piece of code.

The third answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1893653/2241802 
talks about the how Garbage Collector behavior differs in Release mode and Debug mode.

So that was my problem, when i ran the code pasted in the question in Release mode, it worked fine and the excel.exe quit gracefully.

However, to make it work in the Debug mode I took the suggestion of the Thrid Answer link above and created a function which implemented the excel writing stuff.

Answer (score -1):

Find below code

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int randomvalue = new Random().Next(10);
        try
        {
            filename = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/Tro_Reports" + randomvalue + ".xlsx");
            using (var getReportCollection = new DataSet1())
            {
                using (var tableCollection = getReportCollection.Tables["SheetNames"])
                {
                    var excelApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

                    try
                    {
                        var wb = excelApplication.Workbooks.Add();

                        var collection = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet[20];

                        for (var i = 0; i < tableCollection.Columns.Count; i++)
                        {
                            collection[i] = wb.Worksheets.Add();
                            collection[i].Name = tableCollection.Columns[i].ToString();
                        }
                        var thisWorksheet = collection[2];
                        var thisRange = thisWorksheet.Range["A1"];
                        thisRange.Value = "Event Summary Report";

                        wb.SaveAs(filename);
                        wb.Close();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApplication);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ExternalException ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

The above code snippet will work fine to close your excel sheet.

Comment: I suspect that the line `xlWorkBook.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);` is closing the workbook.

Comment: yes. It can close work book. What is the need to close work book after GC.Collect() ?

Comment: Calling `GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();` in the OP's code effectively does nothing.